# RESTHeart PATCH not updating the document

Tags: mongodb, restheart

I am trying to update a key in the MongoDB document using RESTHear api but the value is not getting updated, however, I am getting 200 OK.

I tried PATCH and PUT both. Below are the URIs I tried.

```
http PUT "http://localhost:8080/presence/active_watchers?filter={'presentity_uri':'sip:service-1@opensipstest.org'}" event_id=12

http PATCH "http://localhost:8080/presence/active_watchers?filter={'presentity_uri':'sip:service-1@opensipstest.org'}" event_id=12
```

Both the time I got 200 OK response but the value didn't update.

Am I doing something wrong. I couldn't find any example for this.

I am using Restheart v 2.0.0 Beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bulk update documents matching a filter expression do

`http PATCH "http://localhost:8080/presence/active_watchers/*?filter={'presentity_uri':'sip:service-1@opensipstest.org'}" event_id=12`

If you PUT/PATCH the URI `/presence/active_watchers` you actually update the collection properties (in RESTHeart dbs and collections have their own properties).

To update documents, you need to provide a document URI `/db/coll/docid` and for bulk updates you can use the wildcard `/db/coll/*?filter=[filter expression]`

See [Resource URI](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/ToCM) in the documentation form more information.

Comment: Could see this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111526/how-to-update-single-object-with-restheart-patch.