# How to update single object with RESTHeart patch?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, restheart

I am using RESTHeart and MongoDB. I have multiple JSON objects and I want to update a particular object at a time with a REST call.
I am following https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/RH/pages/9207882/Reference+sheet
, But I am not able to update my object. patch call is not give me 200 ok status.

I am able to use *patch*, but I am not able to find out a particular object for the update.

```
Rh.one('db')
  .one('api')
  .patch(counter, {}, {})
  .then(function(response){

});
```

When I try some condition *if-match* in curly braces then I get this error:

***412 (Precondition Failed)*** **LIKE**

```
Rh.one('db')
  .one('api')
  .patch(counter, {}, {"If-Match": index.name})
  .then(function(response){

});
```

I want to update particular object with patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a document the URI needs to be `/db/coll/<docid>`

You are missing the document ID in the request URL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I am getting 200 ok status. But My object is not updating. I am following this syntax, Rh.one('rdb').one('collectionname').patch({ "If-Match": etag }, { 'counter': 15 }, {}).then(

Comment: In network I am hitting http://localhost:8080/_logic/ls/service/risk/rdb/collectionname?counter=15 And give me 200 ok with patch

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are trying to do. First the /_logic URI prefix means your are dealing with a custom handler; you have to check if it handles PATCH verb. Second the If-Match is an header used to avoid ghost writes, (see in documentation) but the custom handler should handle it... Can you please better explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the answer